# TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

The following code works. It does an ajax request and then call 2 actions, on at a time:

```
export const loadThingsEpic = action$ => {

  return action$.ofType(LOAD_THINGS)
    .mergeMap(({things}) => {
      const requestURL = `${AppConfig.serverUrl()}/data/things`;
      return ajax.getJSON(requestURL)).map(response => {
        return finishLoadingThings(response);
      }).map(() => {
        return sendNotification('success');
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return concat(of(finishLoadingThings({ things: {} })),
                    of(sendNotification('error')));

    });   
}}
```

But this code does not:

```
export const loadThingsEpic = action$ => {

  return action$.ofType(LOAD_THINGS)
    .mergeMap(({things}) => {
      const requestURL = `${AppConfig.serverUrl()}/data/things`;
      return ajax.getJSON(requestURL).switchMap(response => {
        return concat(of(finishLoadingThings(response)),
                      of(sendNotification('success')));
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return concat(of(finishLoadingThings({ things: {} })),
                    of(sendNotification('error')));
    });   
}
```

I've replace the map by a switchMap to merge 2 actions together (as seen in many other post). It works in the catch if an exception is thrown. I'm wondering whats wrong with the code. I'm guessing it's because I can't seem to really grasp when to use: map, swicthMap and mergeMap.

sendNotification and finishLoadingthings returns action object:

```
export function finishLoadingThings(data: any) {
  return {
    type: FINISH_LOADING_THINGS,
    data,
  };
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that the first code seems to work, but the first action is never received by a reducer... I'm very so confused...

Comment: I think I can help. Can you simplify the examples or provide the definitions of the various functions used? Want to make sure it’s clear what they all do and return.

Comment: I simplified the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided as-is appears to work as intended: https://jsbin.com/becapin/edit?js,console I do not receive a "invalid object where stream expected" error when the ajax succeeds or fails.

Are you sure the error is coming from this code?

---

On a separate note, you might be happy to hear that `Observable.of` supports an arbitrary number of arguments, each one will be emitted after the other. So instead of this:

```
.switchMap(response => {
  return concat(of(finishLoadingThings(response)),
                of(sendNotification('success')));
});
```

You can just do this:

```
.switchMap(response => {
  return of(
    finishLoadingThings(response),
    sendNotification('success')
  );
});
```

This would not have caused a bug though, it's just cleaner.

Comment: After cleaning up my epic, it seem to work out of the box. Thanks for the tips, this really help! RxJS is a bit hard to get started with, but I really think it will pay off when the app grows.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fix my problem, by doing the switchMap at the same level than the mergeMap. Like this:

```
export const loadThingsEpic = action$ => {

  return action$.ofType(LOAD_THINGS)
    .mergeMap(({things}) => {
      const requestURL = `${AppConfig.serverUrl()}/data/things`;
      return ajax.getJSON(requestURL).switchMap(response => {
        return of(response);
      });
    })
    .switchMap((res) => {
       return concat(of(finishLoadingThings(res.value)),
                      of(sendNotification('success')));
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return concat(of(finishLoadingThings({ things: {} })),
                    of(sendNotification('error')));
    });   
}
```

Don't quite get it yet.

Comment: placing the catch on the top-level is not the same as inside the mergeMap. It's very likely you won't want that behavior--the epic stops listening for future `LOAD_THINGS` when there's an error.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Same thing with takeUntil at the top level: as soon as the action type is receive the epic just stop.

Comment: To better understand why, try to learn more about how Observable chains actually work. You'll really level-up once you do: https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87